# View Particular List Item MS-Flow History

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate

I'm trying find the way to identify the Power Automate instance history which was ran for particular list item in SharePoint Online.

I found this post [View SharePoint Item\Document Flow history](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/View-SharePoint-Item-Document-Flow-history/idi-p/44286)
  for which idea is submitted.

Anyone know any other way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

This will not help you retroactively for instances that have already run, however,  in your Flow, if you use the expression:

```
concat('https://us.flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/', workflow()['tags']['environmentName'], '/flows/', workflow()['name'], '/runs/', workflow()['run']['name'])
```

This will generate the hyperlink to the specific run history item of the currently running instance of your flow.  If you had a column in the same SharePoint list that is triggering your Flow named something like `[LastFlowRunHistoryLink]`, then your Flow could set the value of that field to the above expression as one of its execution actions.  At that point, your SharePoint item would always have a hyperlink to the last Flow instance that ran for that item.

More about [using expressions here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/use-expressions-in-actions/).

Note:  If you are using a government tenant, make sure the replace the `us.flow.microsoft.com` in the first `concat` parameter with the base Flow url for your sovereign government tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no great answer. The best we can do is to look at the time stamp of when the Flow was triggered. If the flow trigger is the creation or modification of an item in a SharePoint list, for example, this should be easy to track down. If its triggered by a user clicking a button in a power app, this can get a bit trickier. But perhaps the flow takes an action that causes a timestamp to be recorded somewhere? Perhaps the send date of an email?

With that info, sign into Flow and get to the dashboard page for the flow, and you should be able to access a list of all the flow runs. Hopefully you can find the specific flow based on the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information currently.

Per my knowledge, the only way to view the flow history is going to the flow. No easy way to find the history runing for particular list item in SharePoint Online. Like this:

[image]